# When I add remote to Jquery Validate form submits when invalid

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-validate

When I add remote to the jquery validate my form submits even if there are errors, when I remove remote it works properly and you can't submit the form and unless you have filled in all fields? Any ideas? code is below

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#SignUp").validate({
        onsubmit: true,
        onkeyup: function(element) { $(element).valid(); },
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                password: true
            },
            confirm_password: {
                equalTo: "#password",
                required: true
            },
            company: {
                nls:true,
                required: true
            },
            telephone: {
                required: true,
                phoneUK: true
            },
            email2: {
                email: true
            },
            website: {
                url: true
            },
            address1: {
                nls:true
            },
                address2: {
                nls:true
            },
            town: {
                nls:true    
            },
            postcode: {
                postcodeUK:true
            },
            country: {
                selectcountry:true
            },
            terms:{
                required:true               
            },
            answer:{ 
                remote: "Captcha/check-captcha.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                        captcha: function() {
                        return $("#answer").val();
                                }
                        }

            }
        },
        messages:{
            email:
                    {
                        required: "Please Enter an Email Address"
                    },
            password:
                    {
                        required: "Please Enter a Password"
                    },
            confirm_password:
                    {
                        required: "Please Confirm Your Password"
                    },
            company:
                    {
                        required: "Please Enter Your Company/Climbing Gym Name"
                    },
            telephone:
                    {
                        required: "Please Enter a Telephone Number"
                    },
            terms:
                    {
                        required: "Please Agree Our Terms and Conditions"
                    },
            answer:{
                        remote: "You Have Entered The Captcha Correctly When This Message Disappears"
                    }

        }
    });

    $.validator.addMethod("password", function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&*()_]{6,16}$/i.test(value);
    }, "Passwords are 6-16 characters");

    $.validator.addMethod("nls", function(value, element)
    {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s.\-_']+$/i.test(value);
    }, "Please Only Enter Alpha Numeric Characters and Spaces"); 


    jQuery.validator.addMethod('selectcountry', function (value) {
        return (value != 'Nothing');
    }, "Please Select a Country");

    $.validator.addMethod("url", function(value, element)
    {
    return this.optional(element) || /^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/i.test(value);
    }, "Please Enter A Valid Website URL");





});
</script>
```

PHP is below:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(strtolower($_REQUEST['answer']) == $_SESSION['captcha']){    
echo 'true';die;
}else{
 echo 'false';die;

}
?>
```

The validation still works onkeyup etc with and without remote but just not on submit?

Comment: the remote rule should be `answer: {
                remote: {
                    url: "Captcha/check-captcha.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        captcha: function () {
                            return $("#answer").val();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
`

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is the remote validation from client side using ajax is not enough the captcha need to be validated in the submit handler of the form submit

Comment: Cheers Arun, spot on answer, silly mistake, many thanks

Comment: if that was the problem I'll post it as an answer. I did post it because I was unable to recreate the problem

Comment: You should read [the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate) about the `onsubmit` option.  Setting it to `true` is **not** valid.  It's enabled by default, so leave it out entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The remote rule syntax is slightly off in your case

```
answer: {
    required: true,
    remote: {
        url: "Captcha/check-captcha.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            captcha: function () {
                return $("#answer").val();
            }
        }
    }
}
```